# How to style an autocomplete jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete

I just tried autocomplete plugin and I have a problem somewhere with the style. See picture.

[image]

As you can see, when the dropdown is shown , it too large.

the HTML code :

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'rechercher_personne', 'class'=>'navbar-form-custom', 'method' => 'get')) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="rechercher_personne" class="form-control typeahead" type="text" name="personne" placeholder="Rechercher personne ..." pattern=".{2,}" title="2 caractères minimum" >
            <input type="hidden" id="url_for_ajax" value="{{URL::to('/')}}" />
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}" name="currentRouteName">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_personne" class="form-control"/>

            <!-- <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>  -->

        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

I use the bootstrap classes. I tried to play with "col-md-2" without effect. How to style that more properly ?

thanks for your help.

Dominique

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. only had this :

```
 open: function(){
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '200px');
        }
```

Dominique